# Does loc/iloc return a reference or a copy?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am experiencing some problems while using .loc / .iloc as part of a loop. This is a simplified version of my code:

```py
INDEX=['0', '1', '2', '3', '4']
COLUMNS=['A','B','C']
df=pd.DataFrame(index=INDEX, columns=COLUMNS)
i=0

while i<1000:

    for row in INDEX:
        df.loc[row] = function()
    #breakpoint

    i_max = df['A'].idxmax()
    row_MAX=df.loc[i_max]

    if i == 0:
        row_GLOBALMAX=row_MAX
    elif row_MAX > row_GLOBALMAX:
        row_GLOBALMAX=row_MAX

i+=1
```

basically:

1. I initialize a dataframe with index and columns
2. I populate each row of the dataframe with a for loop
3. I find the index "i_max" finding the maximum value in column 'A'
4. I save the row of the dataframe where the value is maximum 'row_MAX'
5. The while loop iterates over steps 2 to 4 and uses a new variable 
   row_GLOBALMAX to save the row with the highest value in row 'A'

The code works as expected during the first execution of the while loop (i=0), however at the second iteration (i=1) when I stop at the indicated breakpoint I observe a problem:
both 'row_MAX' and 'row_GLOBALMAX' have already changed with respect to the first iteration and have followed the values in the updated 'df' dataframe, even though I haven't yet assigned them in the second iteration.

basically it seems like the .loc function created a pointer to a particular row of the 'df' dataframe instead of actually assigning a value in that particular moment. 
Is this the normal behaviour? 
What should I use instead of .loc?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I **think** both `loc` and `iloc` (didn't test `iloc`) will **point** to a specific index of the dataframe. They do not make copies of the row.

You can use the `copy()` method on the row to solve your problem.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

INDEX=['0', '1', '2', '3', '4']
COLUMNS=['A','B','C']

df=pd.DataFrame(index=INDEX, columns=COLUMNS)

np.random.seed(5)

for idx in INDEX:
    df.loc[idx] = np.random.randint(-100, 100, 3)

print("First state")
a_row = df.loc["3"]
a_row_cp = a_row.copy()

print(df)
print("---\n")
print(a_row)

print("\n==================================\n\n\n")

for idx in INDEX:
    df.loc[idx] = np.random.randint(-100, 100, 3)

print("Second state")
print(df)
print("---\n")
print(a_row)
print("---\n")
print(a_row_cp)
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I have tried the code adding the .copy() method and that worked fine :)

Answer (score 1):

According to the official documentation

```
df.loc[] = value
```

becomes

```
df.loc.__setitem__((slice())), value)
```

so there is no copy of the original data-frame created anywhere. The operation is done on a view of the original data-frame. **This is the suggested way of assignment.**.

`df.loc[]` is guaranteed to be `df` itself with modified indexing behavior, so `df.loc.__getitem__` / `df.loc.__setitem__` operate on df directly.

The problems and uncertainty (view vs copy) start in cases of chained indexing for which you can read more [here.](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#why-does-assignment-fail-when-using-chained-indexing)

Also, be aware that sometimes the assignment warnings by pandas may be false positive -> i.e. when you are correctly using `df.loc[]` for assignment but get a warning telling you that you should be using `df.loc[]`...